# How to test Push notification listening

Tags: android, firebase, delphi, push-notification

I don't receive the test push notifications in my android application.

I've done all the Firebase push notification reception steps in delphi 12, and I get the device token. When I test sending a notification from the Firebase console with this token, I receive nothing in the application.

Can you suggest any other tests or checks to find out what's causing the problem ?